# CNN convolutional layer backpropagation formulas

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, convolution

I tried to implement a CNN in Java but I am stuck at updating the weights in my convolution layer.

I tried to create the following image that shows how I calculate each weight delta and error signals:

[image]

I searched the internet but did not find a solution so it would be great if someone in here could tell me what I did wrong.

Greetings, Finn

Comment: You should explain more what you think is wrong and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Well, I applied the formula and my network seems not to learn the kernels correctly. I do not really know what part of the formula is wrong. Maybe everything is correct and I just did not apply the formula correctly. But I think thats very unlikely. Have you found a mistake?

Comment: I think your problem is it is hard to verify the output. I suggest to follow this link https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/ You can verify that your output and update values are correct or not